# Can not install .ipa in iPad 5.0

Tags: ios, ipad, installation, ipa

I did a very simple application containing just a UiWebView and developed using XCode 4.5.2. I can install this application (using iTunes) in a 6.0 iPad retina and run it with no problems but not in a 5.0 iPad. If I try to install in a iPad 5.0 nothing happens. No error message, nothing.

This is what I do:

1. In Apple development site I build a provisioning profile
   containing both devices IDs. iPad 5.0 and iPad 6.0 retina.
2. Import this provisioning profile in XCode.
3. In XCode project target->summary->iOS application target, I have: Devices=iPad and
   Deployment Target=5.0
4. In XCode project target->build
   settings->architecture, I have: Architectures=armv6 armv7 armv7s,
   Base SDK=Latest iOS(iOS 6.0), Supported platforms = iOS, Valid
   Architectures= armv6 armv7 arv7s.
5. In XCode project target->build
   settings->Code Signing, I have Code signing Identity (all entries)
   with my imported provisioning profile.
6. In Xcode
   Product->Archives. The app is building with no erros. In Organizer
   click distribute and select "Save for enterprise or Ad-Hoc
   Deployment". Using my "Code Sign Identity" I saved my .ipa (Save for
   Enterprise Distribution not selected). 7) After sent this .ipa to my
   test partner and installation works on iPad 6.0 retina but not in
   iPad 5.0.

What I´m doing wrong? I already spent 3 days searching Google and StackOverflow and no answer worked for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure the UDIDs of the two iPads are correct.

Also you need to install the provisioning profile on that other iPad.

An easier way to distribute your app might be to use [TestFlightApp](https://testflightapp.com/).